# How to perform conditional de-duplication in talend

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have a table with the employee ID, name, and last effective date. I want to keep only the employee ID with max(last effective date) and discard the other duplicate employee id rows that have an earlier last effective date.

I am trying to implement this using`tAggregate` and `tFilterRow`. I attemped to perform count using `tAggregate` but it does not capture max(lasteffectivedate).

Answer (score 1):

With a tAggreggateRow you can do :

[image]

If you want to get the ID too you need to reuse your primary flow in tMap (Main branch) and put the flow with the tAggregateRow in the lookup of the tMap.
After that you do a join on name AND date.